# Swift - Make the labels on constructor parameters optional?

Tags: constructor, swift

Let's say, for instance, you have the following code:

```
struct SomeStruct {
     init (arg1: String, arg2: Int){
          // Does Stuff with Variables
     }
}

// Some Point Later

var str = "fasfsad"
var integer = 343
let smth = SomeStruct(arg1: str, arg2: integer)
```

Is it possible to modify the SomeStruct struct to make the following line of code legal?

```
let smth = SomeStruct(str, integer)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can make the parameters anonymous by using an underscore for the external parameter name:

```
struct SomeStruct {
     init (_ arg1: String, _ arg2: Int){
          // Does Stuff with Variables
     }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but to split hairs on the original question's wording: this doesn't make parameter labels *optional* at the call site — it makes it required that the caller omit them. A function/initializer declaration specifies exactly one syntax for calling it. If you want to provide callers with multiple options, declare multiple initializers.

Comment: That's a good point. If the initializer is defined this way, `SomeStruct(arg1: str, arg2: integer)` is no longer a valid call.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do this:

```
struct A {
    var a: String
    var b: String

    init(_ a: String,_ b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}

var x = A("S", "B")
```